# Remotely Writable NFC Tags

Tags: nfc

I am developing a solution to open doors via NFC tags. These NFC tags will only hold the door identifier, with which the door can then be opened. However, I want to prevent people from reading the identifier once and then sending the identifier to a friend who could then remotely start the door opening process.

So far, the system used QR codes that were displayed on screen and changed every 10 seconds. The QR codes contained secrets that were only valid for a few minutes.

**Do you know of any NFC tags or tag emulators that are capable of being rewritten remotely, e.g., via WLAN?**

For example, is it possible to emulate an NFC tag using a Raspberry Pi, and to then change the content of the emulated tag every 10 seconds? Are there even cheaper, smaller, or more simple solutions?

I realize that this question is not a software question and I apologize, but StackOverflow is my go-to place for technical questions and I am sure you can help me or point me to a place where I am helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on NT3H2111_2211 from NXP you can see more details about it [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NT3H2111_2211.pdf)
you can rewrite NDEF messages and EEPROM ,SRAM with microcontroller by I2C.
you can even write all tages values by one Micro controller and drive this mircocontroller wirelessly.